# Macro excel if else statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro to check the cell in one whole column. I compare the first cell, with the second cell, the second cell with the third cell, if the subsequent cell is smaller than the previous cell, I will add a whole row of zeros between them, how should i do it?

I have something like this:

```
Sub hello()
    For i = 1 To 10000
        If (C1 - C2 > 1) Then
            C2.EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But it fails, what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: How does it fail? Please be specific.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, I have changed 10000 value as end of row statement. So you don't have to change For loop for every case and get rid of unnecessary loops. After inserting a new row, you have to increment i value twice to skip empty row that is created because of difference. And while adding a new row, you have to select i+1 because excel adds new row and shift down the values by default.

```
Sub hello()
       For i = 1 To Range("A10000").End(3).Row
           If (Cells(i, 1) - Cells(i + 1, 1) > 1) Then
               Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
               i = i + 1
       End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: A little explanation about the code would improve your answer drastically.